# Hive JDBC Connection NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am using Hive 2.1.1 and trying to create a connection. Following is the code I am trying:

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Register driver and create driver instance

    Class.forName(driverName);
    // get connection

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    stmt.executeQuery("CREATE DATABASE userdb");
    System.out.println("Database userdb created successfully.");

    con.close();
}
```

These are my classpaths declared in bashrc:

> CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-2.1.1.jar
>   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:.
>   CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib

I am getting the error below.

> ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default
>   configuration: logging only errors to the console. Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/metadata/HiveException  at
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService.(EmbeddedThriftBinaryCLIService.java:33)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.(HiveConnection.java:163)
>     at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
>   com.raad.ams.bean.HiveJdbc.main(HiveJdbc.java:17)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use "hive-jdbc-**standalone**-2.1.1.jar" to get rid of the dependency headaches...

Comment: Caveat: even with the so-called "standalone" JAR you will also need `hadoop-common.jar` and `commons-configuration.jar` in CLASSPATH, and possibly `hadoop-auth.jar` (required for Kerberos)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i would suggest : Create a Maven/ Gradle project and add Hive-jdbc in pom. It will download all dependencies.

Otherwise check this : [Dependencies](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/2.1.1/hive-jdbc-2.1.1.pom)

You need to include all jars which are under dependencies tag.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue where we were getting `noclassdeffound` error working on `Robot automation framework` and `Hive`. It looks to be jar compatibility issue. We resolved it by adding the latest `hive jdbc` maven dependency to the pom file and it worked.
You should check for all the required Hive related jars and update them accordingly.